# Angular dynamic imports

Tags: angular

I'm updating an angular application from version 8 to 9. Following the [Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-9.0), I need to use dynamic imports in my modules for lazy loaded routes. It says `ng update` should take of this automatically. Executing `ng-update` seems to only list packages to be updated. Is this supposed to be updating my routes or do I need to perform those updates manually?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The command `ng update` is supposed to do that for your, translating

```
loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
```

to

```
loadChildren: () => import('./lazy/lazy.module').then(m => m.LazyModule)
```

As stated in the official documentation [[Read more here]](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#loadchildren-string-syntax):

> Version 8 update: When you update to version 8, the ng update command
> performs the transformation automatically. Prior to version 7, the
> import() syntax only works in JIT mode (with view engine).

Comment: Why does my ng update just list packages?

Comment: In the screenshot you uploaded in your updated OP, the CLI is informing you about the available updates specification and the packages concerned with the update. That's IMHO a good thing they do. Because if they do not state that ahead of time and they make it performs in a sandboxed blind manner that can cause sever problems. Now as you have the packages listed it is up to you to execute the listed commands in the third row in the screenshot to perform the update

Comment: That's fine, I'm, just not seeing it update my imports in the routing module to be dynamic

Comment: I see, I think for version 8 you need to add this flag    `--migrate-only`     during execution

Comment: Here is the issue reported on the github repo and what worked for other people: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14589#issuecomment-509544127